# Load data from server using swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I try to load the user profile like below

```
@IBAction func Btn_LoadDataFromDataBase(_ sender: UIButton) {       
  let myurl = "site.com/profile.php"
  LoadURL(url: myurl)        
    }

 func LoadURL(url: String) {
        do{
            let appURL = URL(string: url)! // convert string to URL
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: appURL)
//error here on this line below :
            let json1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data ) as! [String: Any]
            print(json1) 
            let query1 = json1["profile"] as! [String: Any]
            print(query1) 

           label_email.text = "Email : (query1["email"]!)"

        }catch{
            print("error in url")
        }
}
```

if I test the json via webbrowser I get it like this:

```
{profile :  [{"0":"999","id":"999","1":"1","email":"blabla@gmail.com","2":"1111","tel":"00122222222","3":"0" ..........
```

php code:

```
print "{profile : ".json_encode($user_profile,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."}";  
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Never load remote data synchronously on the main queue. Avoid using `Data(contentsOf:)`. Use `URLSession` to load remote data.

Comment: As others have said, loading remote data synchronously is a bad idea. If the remote server takes too long your UI freezes and your app can be terminated for being non-responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the JSON carefully, there are only two different collection types

- `{}` is dictionary (`[String: Any]`)
- `[]` is array (`[Any]` but in most cases `[[String: Any]]`)

so the result for `query1` (I changed the variable names to something more descriptive) is an array and you need a loop to print all elements:

```
 let profileData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data ) as! [String: Any]
 let profiles = profileData["profile"] as! [[String: Any]] // could be even [[String:String]]
 for profile in profiles {
     print("Email :", profile["email"]!")
 }
```

I'm wondering why so many owners of web services send the PHP arrays unnecessarily with both index and key.

And **never** load data from a remote URL synchronously, use asynchronous `URLSession`

Comment: I get error on the same line too-> `let profileData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data ) as! [String: Any]`

Comment: Then the actual JSON does not match the JSON in the question.

Comment: the php code is like this : `print "{profile : ".json_encode($user_profile,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."}";  `

Answer (score 1):

You're better using **URLRequest** for async requests. You will need to pass your appURL as a parameter in a URLRequest and handle the answer in its completion handler.

An example:

```
let urlString = "https://swift.mrgott.pro/blog.json"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        // Implement JSON decoding and parsing
        do {

            let articlesData = try JSONDecoder().decode([OBJECT YOU WANT].self, from: data)

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: While using `URLSession` is much better, the OP's code is loading the data using `Data(contentsOf:)` initializer.

Comment: You're right, didn't notice OP was using Data to load the contents of it.